# Increasing timeout for LBAPI request

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I've been working on an app that uses the LBAPI to gather all the leaf work items within our workspace when the app is first ran. This is expected to take some time, seeing as there are over 25,000 and I'm pulling several fields for each item. However, recently the requests seem to be timing out at around the 30 second mark. I would assume this is a setting within the SDK, however I found no way to change the timeout anywhere in the documentation. To make matters worse, rather than returning to the callback function an "unsuccessful" response, there is no response at all, which makes exception handling much more difficult on my end.

I was wondering, is there in fact a way to increase this timeout? And if not, is there are more elegant way to catch that event, rather than simply setting a timer on my end as well, and assuming once it gets to zero without a request there was an error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

30 second default is probably low for 20K page size. Changing pagesize to 10k with limit set to infinity may help. Also, given a `Rally.data.WsapiDataStore` or `Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore` try

```
store.getProxy().timeout = 60000;
```